# traceroute -A - how does the lookup work?

Tags: traceroute, peering

How does the `traceroute -A` command work? How does the program look up the ASN? On which protocols or databases does the query depend? Can I recreate the `-A` option?

I am using this version: `Modern traceroute for Linux, version 2.0.18, Jun 30 2012`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A whois query is made for every IP returend.

Here is a manual example. Get one of the IPs of networkengineering.stackexchange.com

```
> host networkengineering.stackexchange.com
networkengineering.stackexchange.com has address 104.16.12.128
networkengineering.stackexchange.com has address 104.16.14.128
networkengineering.stackexchange.com has address 104.16.15.128
networkengineering.stackexchange.com has address 104.16.13.128
networkengineering.stackexchange.com has address 104.16.16.128
```

And check which AS the IP belongs to:

```
 > whois 104.16.12.128  | grep -i origin
 OriginAS:       AS13335
```

Whois outpus way more information. The protocol ist specified in [RFC3912](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3912)

Note that whois output of the regional registries differ and not all will provide the origin as. So traceroute -A will not provide AS informations for all addresses.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: LACNIC: `whois 200.26.79.202`, `whois 200.32.33.54`, `whois 209.13.168.154`, do not reveal the ASN. Neither does the tool at [lacnic.net](http://lacnic.net/cgi-bin/lacnic/whois?lg=EN). The ASNs shown by `traceroute` are: 200.26.79.202 [AS4967/AS10834]; 200.32.33.54 [AS5648]; 209.13.168.154 [AS4926].

Comment: APNIC: `whois 202.108.38.254` does not reveal the ASN. Neither does the tool at [apnic.net](https://wq.apnic.net/apnic-bin/whois.pl). But `traceroute` shows AS4808. On the contrary, querying `whois 219.158.97.165` via the form at [apnic.net](https://wq.apnic.net/apnic-bin/whois.pl) shows an additional section: `% Information related to '219.158.96.0/19AS4837'`. That's the same ASN as identified by `traceroute`. Still, `whois 219.158.97.165` does not reveal the ASN.

Comment: I've done all traceroutes again. On two hosts, using different ISPs. For each hop a Whois query is sent to 198.108.0.18. I could manually query each hop via `jwhois -f -h 198.108.0.18 $IPv4`. Searching the web for `"198.108.0.18" whois` did lead me to [RADB](http://www.radb.net/support/query2.php). To sum it up: `traceroute` does not ask a RIR, as `whois` does without the `-h` option.

Comment: This answer is obviously wrong. There is no way to reliably get origin AS from whois objects. Please refrain from spreading misinformation if you don't have sources to support it.

Comment: @sdaffa23fdsf: There is always the source code of any traceroute version supporting AS resolution. If you don't want to read source use wireshark to capture what a traceroute -A is doing to get the AS number.

Comment: @sdaffa23fdsf Check for yourself with Wireshark, I have, traceroute is triggering WHOIS queries to get the origin AS number for each IP. It isn't gaurenteed you can get the origin AS number in a WHOIS query, which is why traceroute doesn't always have the AS number in it's results when using -A.

Comment: I am calling BS on this. `* google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8) [AS15169]  18.193 ms *` . Plenty of inetnum objects without OriginAS.

Comment: Okay: Would you please explain how traceroute -A is working? It must be some form of magic and the file as_lookups.c in the traceroute source code, where whois.radb.net is queried and the output is searched for "origin", must be fake and only there to confuse people.

Comment: I looked at Dmitry Butskoy's traceroute source code, it does whois lookup on whois.radb.net which explains why 203.208.171.202 shows up in traceroute with wrong ASN. To be accurate as-lookup is based on RADB IRR, not ARIN whois (address registry or ARIN IRR)

Answer (score 1):

--as-path-lookups is based on RADB IRR data, which may very well be incorrect/missing.

traceroute/as_lookups.c in traceroute-2.1.0 Dmitry Butskoy

```
/*
    Copyright (c)  2006, 2007           Dmitry Butskoy
                                        <buc@citadel.stu.neva.ru>
    License:  GPL v2 or any later

    See COPYING for the status of this software.
*/

#define DEF_RADB_SERVER         "whois.radb.net"
#define DEF_RADB_SERVICE        "nicname"
...
if (!ra_addr.sa.sa_family) {
    const char *server, *service;
    struct addrinfo *res;
    int ret;

    server = getenv ("RA_SERVER");
    if (!server)  server = DEF_RADB_SERVER;

    service = getenv ("RA_SERVICE");
    if (!service)  service = DEF_RADB_SERVICE;


    ret = getaddrinfo (server, service, NULL, &res);
    if (ret) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s/%s: %s\n", server, service,
                                            gai_strerror(ret));
        exit (2);
    }   

    memcpy (&ra_addr, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);

    freeaddrinfo (res);
}
...
```

example of incorrect information

```
  * 203.208.171.202 (203.208.171.202) [AS19905]  180.570 ms 203.208.153.254 (203.208.153.254) [AS19905]  187.246 ms
```

based on RADB IRR

```
$ whois -h whois.radb.net 203.208.171.202
route:      203.208.171.0/24
descr:      AC_SINGTEL
origin:     AS19905
mnt-by:     MAINT-AS7786
changed:    wan.engineering@neustar.biz 20150730  #02:53:10Z
source:     RADB
```

[IRR/BGP comparison on IRR Explorer](http://irrexplorer.nlnog.net/search/203.208.171.202)

- 203.208.128.0/17 BGP from AS7473, RADB AS7473
- 203.208.171.0/24 not seen in BGP, Level3 AS19905, RADB AS7473 the
- traceroute hop 203.208.171.202 is actually in AS7473

Moral of the story, there is no way to reliable get a route's origin AS in any static database (IRR, registry etc). And the origin may very well be different depending on your vantage point in DFZ.